# Grant all privileges to all users on a host in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to grant all privileges to all users in mySQL ?

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

What do I replace username with in order to allow it for every user on the given IP?Even if it is `''` i.e no username at all in input ?

I tried `*` and `%` in username but that did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) says:

> In this case, any user who connects from the local host with the
>   correct password for the anonymous user will be permitted access, with
>   the privileges associated with the anonymous-user account.

Comment: I saw this and thought that this means that user who does not enter a username will be granted access.  Do you know for certain that this would allow, for example, `rahul@localhost` to connect?

Comment: it did not work, now it broke and I'm getting error `Access denied for user &#039;product_12345&#039;@&#039;localhost&#039;`

Answer (score 5):

This is working for all my MySQL users irrespective of their hostname and Ips.

```
GRANT ALL ON <yourdbname>.* TO ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourdbpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'database'.'table' TO '%'@'1.2.3.4' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: MySQL does not allow wildcards for the username.

Answer (score 2):

Wild card does not work for user in mysql grant privilege command.

If you know list of users then yOU can try :-

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'1.2.3.4',
 'user2'@'1.2.3.4',
 'user3'@'1.2.3.4',
 'user4'@'1.2.3.4',
 'user5'@'1.2.3.4',
 'user6'@'1.2.3.4';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grant all privileges to all users and be able to use **without a password**, the command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If, for example you hava database named 'my_db' and you doing operations from localhost, the command can be the follow:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO ''@'localhsot' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I get a `Error in your SQL syntax` for those commands

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support wildcards in user names, so you cannot do that in a single grant.
see [the official doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

Answer (score 1):

For MariaDB

```
use mysql;
create user 'USER_NAME'@'192.168.1.%' identified by 'Password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER_NAME'@'192.168.1.%';
select user, host from user;
```